# Transfer data from table 1 to table 2 in MYASQL with help of cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a table in MySQL database(mhk) named "Todays Visitors".
This table collect all the visitors ip all day (from 00:00 to 23:49).
As the next day started (I mean 00:00) all the data in "Todays Visitors" table migrate to "All Visitors" table automatically:.

Comment: This may [help](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: A select into and delete from in a .sql how tough is it? Isn't it fun trying to figure it out?

Comment: I know how to put data on MYSQL. My Question is that how can i migrate data table to table with cron job?

Comment: An insert into... select. You know how to put data

Comment: I want automatically with cron job. I am not familiar with cron job.

Comment: Right but have you even looked into anything

Comment: Yes I search for cron job that I heard cron job do the exact thing want I want but unfortunately I don't know about the cron job script.